# If I accept a meeting invitation more than once, will I send an email more than once?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I'm very confused by outlook calendar, to say the least.

I've received an email with an appointment.

I see an info icon in the email, saying "please respond"

And I see the options to accept, reject or postpone the appointment.

However, I don't remember if I've already accepted the appointment.
If I click again, will I send out another email?

I tried to click on "send the response now", but the email is still marked with "please respond".

However I do see that in my sent email there is an email sent out with "I have accepted the meeting"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually after accepting the reply is sent, it's added to your calendar, & the email invite is deleted. If I remember right even opening it in your Deleted Items it won't let you respond a second time

***--Edit--***
I skimmed your question, apologies. If it's already in your sent email then I think Outlook may be glitching so I'd close it & re-open. It's also possible two meeting invites were sent...

Comment: oh right, there was a delay, between accepting and sending probably. Now it make sense...